# Not getting Order emails copies with personal to my Gmail custom email Magento

Tags: email, magento, smtp, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have a custom gmail domain (myself@customdom.com) and I have set on backend to receive order copies in that email but I am not receiving them. Now, If I add a normal gmail account (myself@gmail.com) it works.

```
myself@customdom.com --> FAILS
myyself@gmail.com --> WORKS
```

I have tried some solutions but they don't seem to work. What is blocking the emails to get to my custom emails? Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `customdom.com` as the domain name your Magento store is sitting on?

i.e `sales@customdom.com` is the "FROM" email address for orders and `myself@customdom.com` is "TO" address

If so I would ensure you have a SPF record set on your domain name as this email is mostly likely being added as spam.

This is a common issue where the web server is trying to "spoof" your email address as a sender and when you try to email yourself, its marked as spam.